# SVN repository structure for cross-platform C++ project

Tags: c++, svn, version-control, cross-platform

We are working on a cross-platform project for the first time.

The source code will obviously be the same for both platforms, however we are unsure about how to handle the project's configuration (VS solution, Unix makefiles etc).

I am very interested to hear from peope who have worked in a similar scenario. We are planning to have one developer care about Windows and one about Unix (Mac later ;-).

Comment: Use cross-platform build system like cmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SVN in a very large cross-platform C++ set of projects.  I put the Makefiles and VS projects in the folder with the source code, and modify the output directories to build into a Binaries folder relative to the main trunk (i.e. in a separate tree from the source/projects).  There are a few oddities that get output by VS that end up in the source tree as you're developing, but you can use SVN to ignore them.  Works out fairly well.